# Uno Platform Winui3: Unathorized Error when calling External API using user token generated by MSAL in Uno Platform Desktop APP(UWP),

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, winui-3, uno-platform

we are developing a Uno Platform desktop application with Winui3, we have a requirement to call one of the api hosted in Azure App service.

we have client App registered in AAD [Multitenant enabled] which is used for desktop users
to signing-in and generate the user token.

Code for generating User Token (desktop app):

```
private static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;
        private static AuthenticationResult authResult;
        public static async Task<(User user, string Token)> InitMSALSignIn()
        {
            User graphUser = null;
           
                // Sign-in user using MSAL and obtain an access token for MS Graph
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = await SignInAndInitializeGraphServiceClient(new string[] { "user.read" });

                // Call the /me endpoint of Graph
                graphUser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
                
            
            return (user : graphUser, Token: authResult.AccessToken);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Signs in the user and obtains an Access token for MS Graph
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scopes"></param>
        /// <returns> Access Token</returns>
        private static async Task<string> SignInUserAndGetTokenUsingMSAL(string[] scopes)
        {
            // Initialize the MSAL library by building a public client application
            PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AppConfig.Msal.ClientAppId) //desktop app clientid from config
                .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
                .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
                .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>
                 {
                     Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL: {level} {message} ");
                 }, LogLevel.Warning, enablePiiLogging: false, enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true)
                .Build();

            
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                                                  .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                                  .ExecuteAsync()
                                                  .ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sign in user using MSAL and obtain a token for MS Graph
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>GraphServiceClient</returns>
        private async static Task<GraphServiceClient> SignInAndInitializeGraphServiceClient(string[] scopes)
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/",
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await SignInUserAndGetTokenUsingMSAL(scopes));
                }));

            return await Task.FromResult(graphClient);
        }
```

The Token generated above is being passed in HTTP headers as Bearer token while calling API

API Startup.cs code for token validation

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                });
```

Actually, this piece of code is working fine when another React Client is calling the same API.
However, when I call this API from Desktop Application, context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated=false is coming in API Authhandler and hence API is returning 401 error.

Please suggest what i am missing in desktop application.

Edit:
I was going through some docs and understood that user token generated with scope "user.read" for calling graph API cant be used directly for calling internal APIs. But not sure how to resolve it. do i need to get another token?

Comment: Do you receive a proper access token?

Comment: You mean token generated in Desktop App? Yes, I get proper access token